# Form attachment instead of basic link

Tags: forms, drupal, phpmailer, mime-mail

I'm using Drupal 9 along with Mime Mail, PHP Mailer and Webform to handle my forms. I'm trying to send an attachement file, instead of having it in a link.

In my handler, I've checked "Include files as attachment", and my file is well checked in Included email values/markup section.

How to make it work ?

I've tried to check the configuration and read a lot of documentation.

Comment: Removed the 'Webforms' tag because I *think* you're referring to an HTML form, not ASP.NET. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly, it's a Webform, HTML. But still can't make it work